# Rails partial for different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I have different controllers that share a lot of functionality and I'm wondering if there is a way to share that similar functionality between them.

For example this:

```
= link_to 'Edit', dvd_path(dvd), :class => 'btn'
```

Where the only thing that changes between controllers is the object, instead of dvd it will be books or games. So I'm thinking there has to be a way to create a partial that uses that controller's correct path without having to rewrite each one. And without having to send the object.

Ideas are appreciated.

**Edit**

@defaye: what I'm trying to do is reuse the code that I have above and apply it to 7 or so different controllers. 
The above code is just an example of a bunch of links and paths that are always the same and the only thing that changes is that dvd_path(dvd) becomes book_path(book), etc.

I'd like the simplest, more straightforward way of doing it.

**In fact, I am now wondering if it's possible to have the same view that handles multiple controllers since they are so similar. This would be fantastic!**

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should add in what you want to avoid otherwise it's too tempting to suggest what you already know (from what I understand reading this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is just a couple of methods, you don't need a partial at all. Helpers can help you.

Here's an example. You can define it in ApplicationHelper.

```
# application_helper.rb
def link_to_edit(object)
  link_to('Edit', polymorphic_path(object, :action => 'edit'), :class => 'btn')
end
```

And in your view

```
= link_to_edit(object)
```

Comment: Sorry for previous post, I didn't know I had to include `module ApplicationHelper` to the top of the file. Now it works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to do it without explicitly sending the object? Shouldn't the class be aware of itself?

Comment: Also, this action does not work: `url_for(:id => object, :action => 'destroy')` it will translate to this: games/:id and invoke the `show` action instead. What's the correct way to call the `destroy` action? Thanks.